# Dataframe vacio con pandas en Sistema recomendador

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buenas a toda la comunidad. Estoy haciendo un proyecto sobre un sistema recomendador simple. Utilizando la libreria `Pandas` de `Python` quiero llenar un dataframe con las coincidencias entre las preferencias del usuario y las peliculas a recomendar.
Tengo 2 `.csv`, una con las peliculas y otro con los ratings. Ambos tienen movieId y si existen coincidecias, pero no se genera el dataframe con esas coincidencias. Solo me pone:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [movieId, Genre, Lead Studio, Audience score %, Profitability, Rotten Tomatoes %, Worldwide Gross, Year, Film, rating]
Index: []
```

Ahora les pongo parte del codigo y si necesitan mas datos, no duden en decirme. Gracias de antemano.
PD.: La parte del ratings no lo mostre porque pienso que ahora poco relevante.

```
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

peliculas = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
rating = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')

# crea columnas y utliza la tecnica One Hot Encoding para codificar las peliculas
peliculas_co = peliculas.copy()
for index, row in peliculas.iterrows():  #pasa x toda la matriz original
    for genre in row ['Genre']:  
        peliculas_co.at[index, genre] = 1   #asigna 1 a cada genero que pertenezca y se guarda en la copia

peliculas_co = peliculas_co.fillna(0)   #asignar 0 a cada genero k no pertenezca
print('Peliculas Codificadas:\n', peliculas_co)  #muestra las peliculas
```

Al final de la tabla, estan los 1 y 0 que se le asignan a cada genero

```
      movieId                                Film    Genre            Lead Studio  Audience score %  Profitability  Rotten Tomatoes % Worldwide Gross  Year    R    o    m    a    n    c    e    C    d    y    D    r    A    i    t    F    s
0         1          Zack and Miri Make a Porno  Romance  The Weinstein Company                70       1.747542                 64         $41.94   2008  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1         2                     Youth in Revolt   Comedy  The Weinstein Company                52       1.090000                 68         $19.62   2010  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2         3  You Will Meet a Tall Dark Stranger   Comedy            Independent                35       1.211818                 43         $26.66   2010  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3         4                        When in Rome   Comedy                 Disney                44       0.000000                 15         $43.04   2010  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4         5               What Happens in Vegas   Comedy                    Fox                72       6.267647                 28        $219.37   2008  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
..      ...                                 ...      ...                    ...               ...            ...                ...             ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
72       73                 Across the Universe  Romance            Independent                84       0.652603                 54         $29.37   2007  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
73       74                       A Serious Man    Drama              Universal                64       4.382857                 89         $30.68   2009  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
74       75                  A Dangerous Method    Drama            Independent                89       0.448645                 79          $8.97   2011  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
75       76                          27 Dresses   Comedy                    Fox                71       5.343622                 40        $160.31   2008  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
76       77                (500) Days of Summer   Comedy                    Fox                81       8.096000                 87         $60.72   2009  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

A continuacion se agrega la identificacion a cada pelicula ingresadas por el usuario. Se filtran las filas que contienen el titulo de la pelicula y se fusiona con la matriz de peliculas original.

```
Id = peliculas[peliculas['Film'].isin(entrada_peli['Film'].tolist())]  # Filtro
entrada_peli = pd.merge(Id, entrada_peli)  # Fusion de matrices
entrada_peli = pd.DataFrame(entrada_peli)
print('Peliculas filtradas para el Usuario:\n', entrada_peli)
```

En este punto es dondese se genera el error del Dataframe vacio que describo en el principio ¿pueden ayudar?

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [movieId, Genre, Lead Studio, Audience score %, Profitability, Rotten Tomatoes %, Worldwide Gross, Year, Film, rating]
Index: []
```

Aqui le muestro parte del dataset de movie:

```
movieId,Film,Genre,Lead Studio,Audience score %,Profitability,Rotten Tomatoes %,Worldwide Gross,Year
1,Zack and Miri Make a Porno,Romance,The Weinstein Company,70,1.747541667,64,$41.94 ,2008
2,Youth in Revolt,Comedy,The Weinstein Company,52,1.09,68,$19.62 ,2010
3,You Will Meet a Tall Dark Stranger,Comedy,Independent,35,1.211818182,43,$26.66 ,2010
4,When in Rome,Comedy,Disney,44,0,15,$43.04 ,2010
5,What Happens in Vegas,Comedy,Fox,72,6.267647029,28,$219.37 ,2008
6,Water For Elephants,Drama,20th Century Fox,72,3.081421053,60,$117.09 ,2011
7,WALL-E,Animation,Disney,89,2.896019067,96,$521.28 ,2008
8,Waitress,Romance,Independent,67,11.0897415,89,$22.18 ,2007
9,Waiting For Forever,Romance,Independent,53,0.005,6,$0.03 ,2011
10,Valentine's Day,Comedy,Warner Bros.,54,4.184038462,17,$217.57 ,2010
```

Aqui estan los dataset de ratings

```
UserId,movieId,Rating,Timestamp
1,61,10,1381620027
1,25,10,1379466669
2,25,8,1394818630
2,72,7,1389963947
2,6,8,1379963769
2,2,7,1391173869
2,45,7,1391529691
2,32,8,1380453043
2,27,8,1387016442
2,42,8,1386350135
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tus `dataset` como texto para que podamos probar. A simple vista yo creo que un problema es que Id se genera de una rebanada del `dataframe` peliculas sin utilizar `loc` o `iloc`.

Comment: Buenos dias, muchas gracias x responder. Actualice la publicacion y agrege los dataset de movie y de ratings. Cogi los 10 primero y por lo que aprecio, solo deberia haber coincidencia el movieId 2 y 6, pero lo dejo a su valoracion.

Comment: buenos dias @HeytalePazguato, segun los datos ofrecidos en la publicacion. que opciones u opiniones me pudieras plantear para arreglar?